# How do I print a sum of numbers after a string in python?

Tags: python, string, numbers

I want to print a sum of numebrs after a string in the same line in python.

```
print("Your answer is correct, this is your score:" + score=score+1)
```

Comment: for python 3 use `f-strings`: `print(f"Your answer is correct, this is your score: {score+1}"`

Comment: @It_is_Chris printing `score+1` isn't equivalent, since they want `score`'s value to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an f-string, but you should also be setting the value of `score` prior to printing it so it's more clear what's happening:

```
score += 1
print(f"Your answer is correct, this is your score: {score}")
```

You can do it your way, but you have to convert `score` to a string before you can concatenate it (via `+`) to another string:

```
score += 1
print("Your answer is correct, this is your score: " + str(score))
```

Another way is to add `score` as an argument to `print`; in that case you don't have to convert it to a string:

```
score += 1
print("Your answer is correct, this is your score: ", score)
```

Comment: also `print("text here...", score)`, print can take any number of arguments

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 to the score *before* printing.

You also need to convert the score to a string before you can concatenate it. Or you can use string formatting, which is simpler.

```
score += 1
print(f"Your answer is correct, this is your score: {score}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a f-string, you can add the operation in the formatting:

```
print(f"Your answer is correct, this is your score: {score+1}")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of way

```
>>> score = 10 #you do your calculation first
>>> print("Your answer is correct, this is your score:", score)#print can take any number of arguments
Your answer is correct, this is your score: 10
>>> print("Your answer is correct, this is your score: " + str(score))#make it a string first and concatenate it
Your answer is correct, this is your score: 10
>>> print(f"Your answer is correct, this is your score: {score}")#use f-string
Your answer is correct, this is your score: 10
>>>
```

and there are like 2 or 3 other way to make string too, but the first and third examples are the one I recommend, specially f-string, they are awesome.

Additionally, in python 3.8 they introduce the [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=` , so you can also do it like you originally tried, with just some adjustments...

```
>>> score=10 
>>> print("Your answer is correct, this is your score:", (score:=score+1))
Your answer is correct, this is your score: 11
>>> score
11
>>>
```